# Weblogic JMS Topic query

Tags: jms, weblogic

Can any tell me where and how (on Weblogic console) can i set a time period i want the messages to stay in a Weblogic JMS Topic or does it stay there forever.

Will the time it stays in the Topic be different in case of the Subscriber to the Topic is a Normal one or a Durable Subscriber ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The producer of the message will set a time a message lives](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive(long)).

A message posted while a normal subscriber is offline will be removed while a message posted when a durable subscriber is offline will stay until the subscriber comes back online.